# Dual x-axis on same line with Highcharts. Possible?

Tags: highcharts

Can we create multiple x-axis chart like [this](https://www.adr.com/DRDetails/CorporateActions?cusip=055622104) using Highcharts?
If yes, can someone please provide some pointers?

There are three year data displayed. i.e. 2010,2011, 2012

https://www.adr.com/DRDetails/CorporateActions?cusip=055622104

Comment: what is the point of doing this why you just don't use highstock with three series and one x-axis ?

Comment: Thanks Mina. However, requirements are like that only. I have to find some way out to get the same look and feel.
Hemang

Comment: Downvoting because the linked resources 404. Please upload images to SO in the future to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Harvey Did you check the date I asked the question? Also, I had accepted the correct answer at that time (2013). 
In 2017, this question might not be even valid. What's the point of downvoting an old question?

Comment: I probably had a similar issue as you but was unable to check to see if your question was the same as mine as the resource has expired. SO recommends allowing users to reproduce your code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using highstocks (highcharts lesser known sibling), you can do something like what you're looking for.  Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twaitsfan/edKRp/)

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function(data) {

    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length;

    for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);

        volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
        ])
    }

    // set the allowed units for data grouping
    var groupingUnits = [[
        'week',                         // unit name
        [1]                             // allowed multiples
    ], [
        'month',
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
    ]];

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Historical'
        },

        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: 200,
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: 300,
            height: 100,
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }, {
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 4):

The older answers didn't run for me in JSFiddle.
Here is a working example, if it helps anyone:

http://jsfiddle.net/kPqKW/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            type: 'datetime'
        }, {
            type: 'datetime',
            opposite: true
        }],

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
        }, {
            data: [176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 10),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
            xAxis: 1
        }]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible, but in different view. one axis at the top and other one is at the bottom. You've set opposite to **true** as we do for y - axis. Have a look at this question in 
[Highcharts forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10921)

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
    },{
        type: 'datetime',
        opposite: true
    }],

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
    },{
        data: [176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 10),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
        xAxis: 1
    }]
});

</script>
```

for working example, look at this   [jsfilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/kSkYN/8029/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Highcharts grouped categories plugin, take a look: https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories

Answer (score 0):

you may go through this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ajaytripathi10/z8mrwhxz/. Hope this will help.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Shared tooltip chart'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
        id: 'x1'
    }, {
        type: 'datetime',
        id: 'x2',
        opposite: true
    }],
    yAxis: {
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
            var tooltip = '';
            var i, len;
            tooltip += '<small>Apple</small>';
            tooltip += '<table>';
            for (i = 0, len = 4; i < len; i++) {
                    if(this.points[i] != undefined){
            if(this.points[i].series.name.indexOf('Apple') >= 0){
                tooltip += '<tr>';
                tooltip += '<td style="color: ' + this.points[i].series.color + '">\u25CF</td>';
                tooltip += '<td>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.points[i].x) + ':</td>';
                tooltip += '<td style="text-align: right"><b>' + this.points[i].y + '</b></td>';
                tooltip += '</tr>';
                }
                }
            }
            tooltip += '</table>';
            tooltip += '<small>Mango</small>';
            tooltip += '<table>';
            for (i = 0, len = 4; i < len; i++) {
                    if(this.points[i] != undefined){
            if(this.points[i].series.name.indexOf('Mango') >= 0){
                tooltip += '<tr>';
                tooltip += '<td style="color: ' + this.points[i].series.color + '">\u25CF</td>';
                tooltip += '<td>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.points[i].x) + ':</td>';
                tooltip += '<td style="text-align: right"><b>' + this.points[i].y + '</b></td>';
                tooltip += '</tr>';
                }
                }
            }
            tooltip += '</table>';
            return tooltip;
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Apple',
        id: 'series1',
        xAxis: 'x1',
        color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 1, 0],
        pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 10)
    }, {
        name: 'Apple New',
        id: 'series2',
        //linkedTo: 'series1',
        xAxis: 'x2',
        color: 'rgba(255, 180, 180, 1.0)',
        data: [4, 5, 5, 6, 1, 3, 4],
        pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 17)
    },{
        name: 'Mango',
        id: 'series3',
        xAxis: 'x1',
        color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)',
        data: [15, 13, 14, 17, 16, 11, 10],
        pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 10)
    }, {
        name: 'Mango New',
        id: 'series4',
        //linkedTo: 'series1',
        xAxis: 'x2',
        color: 'rgba(255, 180, 180, 1.0)',
        data: [14, 15, 15, 16, 11, 13, 14],
        pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 17)
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Complete code for making horizontal and vertical line in column,piechart highcharts

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="col-md-4" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<div id="container2" class="col-md-6" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto" class="col-md-6"></div><div id="container3" class="col-md-6" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto" class="col-md-6" class="col-md-6">dddd</div>
</div>
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',

    },
    title: {
        text: 'sample charts for both horizontal and vertical line'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
        minPadding: 2,
        maxPadding: 2,
        maxZoom: 6 ,
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
             'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {

        title: {
            text: 'Temperature'
        },

        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return  '$'+this.value;
            }
        },

    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                radius: 4,
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
       // name: '',

        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5]

    }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.85
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
            y: 4.67
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.18
        }, {
            name: 'Sogou Explorer',
            y: 1.64
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 1.6
        }, {
            name: 'QQ',
            y: 1.2
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 2.61
        }]
    }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container3', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.85
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
            y: 4.67
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.18
        }, {
            name: 'Sogou Explorer',
            y: 1.64
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 1.6
        }, {
            name: 'QQ',
            y: 1.2
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 2.61
        }]
    }]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```